# Parsing JSON using nested for loop in python

Tags: python, json

I am parsing a huge JSON in python, i am parsing it step by step, i am stuck at a point and i can't figure out why the code is not running properly, my code is;
I want to get value of all the **WHO_REGION** for all the **attr** in an array, as i am not an expert in python programming.....                                                                                    here is the JSON, "http://apps.who.int/gho/athena/data/COUNTRY.json"

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
mylabel = []
mylabel2 = []
with open('C:\Users\Syed Saad Ahmed\Desktop\FL\COUNTRY.json') as   data_file:
data = json.load(data_file)
for i in range(0,246):
    mylabel.append(data["dimension"][0]["code"][i]["label"])
print mylabel
for j in range(0,246):
    for k in range(0,21):
        if(data["dimension"][0]["code"][j]["attr"][k]["category"]=='WHO_REGION'):
            mylabel2.append(data["dimension"][0]["code"][j]["attr"][k]["value"])
print mylabel2
```

Comment: You need to indent the body of `with`

Comment: Don't hardcode the lengths, use `for elem in data["dimension"][0]["code"]:`

Comment: What's the problem you're having? "not running properly" is not an adequate question.

Comment: What is the error message? I notice you're lines after `with` are not indented as well.

Comment: Also, I've used `for key, value in data[stuff_here].items():` to loop through. That may be something to look at instead of hard-coded ranges. Similar to what Barmar suggested above.

Comment: You might want to consider using a library like `pyjq`. Your first loop could be replaced (I think) by something like `mylabel = pyjq.all('.dimension[0].code[].label', data)`, the second with `pyjq.all('.dimension[0].code[].attr[] | select(.category == "WHO_REGION")', data)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can browse your JSON object using nested loops:

```
import json

obj = json.loads(data)

dimention_list = obj["dimension"]
for dimension in dimention_list:
    code_list = dimension["code"]
    for code in code_list:
        attr_list = code["attr"]
        for attr in attr_list:
            if attr["category"] == "WHO_REGION":
                print(attr["value"])
```

It is complex because each entry contains a list of something…

Of course, it's up to you to add some filtering.

Comment: This may be more pythonic, but it looks like his code should work as it is, if he only cares about the first dimension. We need to get him to explain the problem before a good answer can be posted.

Comment: @Laurent , it worked !
Thanks for the help !